# iOS7 moves all UILabels down

Tags: ios6, uilabel, ios7, xcode5

When I'm building my iPhone app for iOS7 all UILabels are moved a little bit downwards. It's just a few points, but all texts are not correctly aligned anymore. If I test on a iOS6 device everything is fine. Is there an easy fix for this or do I have to specify the iOS6/iOS7 deltas in my storyboards and specify positions for iOS6 and iOS7 in my code?

Here is a comparison how it looks like, this happens across the whole application. Thanks a lot for your help!

[image: iOS6/iOS7 UILabel offsets]

Comment: Looks like it's a table view? In that case, is it possible that it's just the new layout of iOS 7 that aligns text in a table cell a bit differently than iOS 6?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not only in the table view (these are custom cells), it's really across the whole app: in regluar views, scroll views, table views, ... The top in this screenshot is a UIView with two UILabels, and those are moved too.

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: Hi Hannes, I think this is related to an issue with iOS 7 I'm also having with a UITextField placeholder. I would suggest to subclass UILabel for all those labels above and override the - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect method to see what the rect is on iOS 6 and what the rect is on iOS 7 (just print it). Then, you could add an if clause (WHICH I HATE TO DO) for different system versions. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Johanneke no, I use manual positioning in the storyboard file and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem. Turns out that my custom font had wrong ascender and descender metrics. Thanks to the guys at kintek there is an easy solution for that: [scroll down to "Fonts" and follow those steps](http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/)

Now the UILabels are still moved down, but the same amount in iOS6 and iOS7. Now I only have to layout all my UILabels correctly and it works in both Versions. If I had that solution from the beginning, no extra work would be needed now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my app when positioning UILabels in a custom view. In iOS 7 the labels aligned perfectly but not so in iOS 6. Changing the *Y value* in the *delta textfield* under *Size Inspector* in the *Utilities* window solved it. In my case I added different values for each label until the various labels were once again in perfect alignment in both iOS versions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (different positions of UILables between iOS6 and 7) but I can't find the iOS6/7 deltas in the Size inspector. I'm using Xcode 5.0.2. Thanks

Comment: @Corrado  I'm on 5.0.2 as well and the delta values are there. Try this: View -> Utilities - Show Size Inspector and right under the springs and struts you'll find the delta values.

Comment: My fault: "Use Autolayout" was selected in the IB Document section of File Inspector ! I hope this can solve my problem of UIlabel different positions between IOS6 and IOS7. Thanks !